# Did any mechanical computers or calculators handle divide by zero with an exception, or did they all loop?

Tags: calculator, mechanical

I just saw this video of a [mechanical calculator dividing by zero.](https://youtu.be/OFJUYFlSYsM) Did any mechanical calculators or computers ever provide for a failure mode on divide by zero? Or did they always handle it by looping infinitely?

[Did any of them have a certain check for the division, or error out on a certain amount of iterations?](https://youtu.be/BRRolKTlF6Q?t=358)

Comment: Given that mechanical calculators would divide by repeated subtraction, possibly with shift, the natural reaction is a loop. Is it worthwhile to add additional mechanics to check for zero, and increase the price of the thing compared to the competition, when the user can easily make sure he never divides by zero? Probably not. So would mechanical calculators exist with this extra check? Probably not.

Comment: It's actually pretty easy to error out on overflow - Simply check for a carry on the uppermost digit and stop the machine. Not a big technical challenge. Some of the late Walthers I've seen that could do division had this.

Comment: @tofro in theory easy to error out on overflow, yes. But how many extra gears do you need to fit for it? As far ad I know, each gear had some manual work in it, so the cost would be increased. I guess that many thought it was better to  just add a warning in the manual. A reason to anyway have the check would be division that anyway would result in overflow.

Comment: @UncleBod The carry is a standard bit in the lower digits - in the upper digits, it's simply not used to transport the next wheel one further, but instead to signal overflow - absolutely no extra effort, when you use the same gear set for all digits.

Comment: @tofro, but something need to catch that carry. That would mean more mechanical parts somewhere.

Comment: @UncleBod Obviously. And that something would need to switch off the motor or raise a red flag on manual machines. And that's exactly what was done.

Comment: @tofro, btw, isn't your first comment an answer? Some did, but not all.

Comment: @tofro Yeah; you should probably write that up as an answer, since answering in comments is problematic.

Comment: Not an answer, but this is reasoning why RISC-V defines that division by 0 causes quotient of all 1 bits. In binary, no need to cycle around each digit, but comparison `rem>=shifted_divisor` is always true.